# Adding key-value pairs to BerkeleyDB using hash access method

Tags: python, berkeley-db

I am trying to create a BerkeleyDB using the hash access method, like so:

```
>>> from bsddb3 import db
>>> dben = DB()
>>> dben.open("filename", None, db.DB_HASH, db.DB_CREATE)
```

However, when I try to insert an entry, nothing works:

```
>>> dben.put(3,2)
```

results in

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       dben.put(3,2)
>   TypeError: Integer keys only allowed for Recno and Queue DB's

Attempting

```
>>> dben[2] = 1
```

it gives the same error.

How do I add an entry to my hash BerkeleyDB?

Using cntrl-space for autocomplete I can see no relevant methods. The same goes for the docs: [PyBSDDB v5.3.0 documentation](http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb_doc/db.html#db-methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only (ugly) workaround on Python 3+ is to encode string to bytes first:

```
dben.put(bytes(str(3), "ascii"), bytes(str(2), "ascii"))
```

or, more conveniently:

```
dben.put(str(3).encode("ascii"), str(2).encode("ascii"))

>>> dben.exists(bytes(2, "ascii"))
False
>>> dben.exists(bytes(3, "ascii"))
True
```

Comment: Be careful, bytes(n) where n is integer creates byte array of length n, it doesn't convert n to bytes! Edited your answer.

Answer (score 1):

bsddb stores as key and value only bytes. So you have to convert your value to bytes first. The prefered method is to use the struct python module.